# How to Limit Access to Specific URIs with Apache

Tags: security, apache-2.4

I have Apache running in front of a webapp whose base URL would be `http://myapp:8080/myApp/`, which proxies to `http://example.com/`. There are several resources following that URL which should be restricted by IP. My problem with solutions I've found online is that they seem to be a blanket restriction on any following URI.

For example, I have:
`http://example.com/search` and `http://example.com/secret`, `http://example.com/admin`, `http://example.com/arbitrary`, etc.

I want everyone to be able to access the `/search` URI, but allow access to all other URI paths only to specified IPs. The problem I'm facing is trying to deny access to the *other* URIs, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was overcomplicating the issue.

This works in the way I want it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /myApp http://localhost:8080/myApp
    ProxyPassReverse /myApp http://localhost:8080/myApp

    <Location /myApp>
        deny from all
        Order deny,allow
        allow from ip1 ip2 ip3
    </Location>
    <Location /myApp/search>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

By default this is forbidding access to every location under `/myApp` but allowing access to `/myApp/search`. Now it's just a case of allowing from particular IPs. I've added that into my answer for completeness.